# How to include html page in another

Tags: html

I want to include html page in other page
for example home and footer page
i want to include footer page in home page
and when run home.html and Ctrl u view source code both page code will be
want to show
please help me
Thanks In advance

Comment: Although you could do this with jQuery this seems much better suited for a server side include.

Comment: see my code hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

Hello according to me you can do it with jquery:

**Home.html**

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedFooterContent").load("footer.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedFooterContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Hope it will work :)

Comment: thanks sir, but when i try to see source code in in browser it will show only home page code, not shown footer page that contains links. i want both page sorce code in home page  source code.

Comment: hello sir, this code is work for showing footer html in home page. but sir i want to see all source code in browser. home page and footer page. on show source code of Home.page

Comment: yes then what you want ? You want footer.html in home page right ?

Comment: i want to show all source code. when i see sorce code of home.html file only div showi.g.i.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>try</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#includedFooterContent").load("Test.htm");
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
 <div id="includedFooterContent"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: this is source code of try.html page like wise home page.

Comment: I dont think you can see that code in view page source. But you can see in inspect element with firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP

You can create you home.html file and can include your footer using the following php code. using this you can view the home.html and footer.html code when you view your page source

```
  <?php include("footer.php");?>
```

Using jquery

You can perform this using jQuery as well, with the following code.
home.html will have

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <div id="footer"> 
  <iframe src="footer.html">
    <p> Footer text</p>
  </iframe>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>

  <script> 
      $(function(){
          $('#footer').load("footer.html"); 
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: thanks sir, but when i try to see code in in browser it will show only home page code. not shown footer page that contains links. if have another solution please tell me. thanks

Comment: Try adding <?php include("footer.php");?> in your home.html and make sure you run this on server since we have php code. Use wamp of xampp server for example it its local file. accept the answer if it helped you :)